# Windows 7 Install USB won't boot after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, 13.10, windows-7

I have replaced Windows 8 with Ubuntu 13.10 and now I am trying to install Windows 7 from a USB but it won't boot. When I choose to boot from my USB it gives an error:

```
This is not a bootable device. Insert a bootable floppy and press any key.
```

The USB was made in the built-in Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you convert Windows 7 to UEFI install? If system was originally Windows 8 it was gpt partitioned. Whether you installed Ubuntu in UEFI or BIOS, drive is probably still gpt and Windows will only install in UEFI mode with gpt partitioning. There supposedly are ways to convert Windows 7 flash to UEFI, but that is a Windows issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I think that Startup Disk Creator doesn't work well with Windows.

You can try creating the usb via winusb as instructed here : [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-to-create-a-windows-8-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Startup Disk Creator will not work for this purpose; it creates only Ubuntu USB Boot keys.
To create a Windows USB Boot you can follow steps listed [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/a/install-windows-7-usb.htm)